# Is it possible to create an ambiguous foreign key that gets defined on its row's creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two database tables, `houses` and `apartments`.  Each of these has its own view page that I would like users to comment on.  Naturally, I also have a `posts` table.  When a post is created it should have a foreign key id referencing the appropriate table (either `houses` or `apartments`).  Is there an efficient method to create some type of ambiguous foreign key for the `posts` table and define it on creation?  As of now, the best solution to my problem I've thought of is to create two foreign key ids (one for `houses` and one for `apartments`) and just have a one column overhead for each `post`.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Single Table Inheritance** allows an object to be defined as separate classes while using only a single database table. This is appropriate for objects that are structurally and functionally similar except for *slight* behavioral differences.

In your case, you have two subclasses, `House` and `Apartment`, which are very similar and can be abstracted to a single superclass, `Dwelling`. This superclass will contain common methods accessible to both houses and apartments. Each subclass will inherit `Dwelling` and expand it with their own subclass-specific methods. You will instantiate a subclass like normal, but internally Rails will be working with a typecast instance of the superclass. As such, you should never instantiate the superclass directly.

It is worth noting that STI combines all attributes into one table. Attributes for one subclass will be present in another, and are *nil* if unused. Subclasses with tons of extraneous attributes will result in bloated tables filled with *nil* values. As a general rule, polymorphic associations should be considered when your subclasses contain more differences than similarities.

---

Here's how we do. <strike>All of this goes in `app/models/dwelling.rb`</strike>:

```
class Dwelling < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  # ...common methods...
end 

class House < Dwelling
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => "dwelling_id"
  # ...house methods...
end

class Apartment < Dwelling
  has_many :posts, :foreign_key => "dwelling_id"
  # ...apartment methods...
end
```

In order for this to work, your `dwelling` table **must contain a string column called "type"**. Rails will see this and automatically know that STI is being used. Note: Both `house` and `apartment` tables will no longer be used by the application. Creating a `House` object will save a new dwelling record to the database, with it's own unique ID and its `type` will be "house".

When assigning a new `Post` to a subclass, use the subclass object's ID. Subclass ID and superclass ID both refer to the same record. Note the `has_many` methods in each of the subclasses. Get a subclass' posts by calling `@house.posts`.

To infer whether a posting was posted to a house or apartment, you may use `@post.dwelling.type`.

---

### Edit:

Rails 3's autoloading behavior expects each class to be in it's own file. Therefore, subclasses must be in their own files respectively:

```
app/
  models/
    apartment.rb
    dwelling.rb
    house.rb
```

Comment: I have successfully implemented this method gg thanks.  I did have a question though.  What's the purpose of the foreign_key declaration in the model?  Since there's only one table (the dwelling table) I'm confused why this is needed.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, both House and Apartment models are stored in the **dwellings** table. Objects belonging to House or Apartment will store a **dwellings_id** key. By default, Rails will expect **house_id** or **apartment_id**, which is incorrect. You must specify the correct foreign key to make forward associations work, ie: `@house.posts`.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphic Association should do the trick. You want posts to either reference a house and an apartment. You will have to add the polymorphic association via your models and then add the appropriate fields for your tables.

If you do decide to go the polymorphic route this how your models would look.

## Posts

```
#Attributes
housing_type :string #Either will `House` or `Apartment`
housing_id :integer #This will reference the id of House or Apartment, depending on what's in your housing_type field

#Associations
belongs_to :housing, :polymorphic => true
```

## Houses

```
#Attributes
post_id :integer

#Associations
has_many :posts, :as => :housing
```

## Apartments

```
#Attributes 
post_id :integer

#Associations
has_many :posts, :as => :housing
```

A basic [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) on understanding and creating a polymorphic association.

And of course a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) on it.

Comment: A polymorphic association is a bit overkill in this case. Here you have two types of what is basically the same object: a dwelling. Single table inheritance would be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: That certainly is one option I overlooked.